# How to call servlet from click event of button

Tags: jsp

Hello guys can we call servlet from a button without the action attribute of the tag??

Like

```
 <button onclick="/SaveHighlights?p=" + <%=line%>+ "&q="+'<%=filename%>'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've some wrong idea about `onclick` event. It executes a javaScript when a button or other is clicked.

Comment: i have one suggestion for you- call  a js function in `onclick` event and then do your stuff into that function.

Comment: Thank you @Khairul Islam

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick` triggers a event, if you want JavaScript code in a servlet you can do so by using`<script>` and `</script>`

Also since you don't want to use Action method you can use:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("DestinationServlet");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i used javascript to call servlet

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <a href="/SaveHighlights?p=" + <%=line%>+ "&q="+'<%=filename%>'><input type="button" name="button" value="save"/> </a>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a bit what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: @scott W....  Sumanth wants to call servlet from jsp(Button click) without any javascript function.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of what it does and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call js function, from that try to trigger a hipper link using "location.href". If you map that link to a servlet in web.xml, it will be invoked.

Note: if you dont want your current page to reload, use a AJAX call. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion